# 413 Request Entity Too Large - File Upload Issue

Tags: php, nginx, apache2

I am trying to upload 30MB file on my server and its not working.

1. When I upload 30MB file, the page loads "**Page Not Found**"
2. When I upload a 3MB file, I receive "**413 Request Entity Too Large**" with nginx/0.6.32

I am trying to find nginx so I can increase "**client_max_body_size**" but I am unable to find nginx installed on my server. I even tried running:

```
vi /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

or

```
vi /usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf
```

to check if the config file exists, but I couldnt find it on my server.

Is there anyway to resolve this issue? Or do I have to installed nginx on my server.

EDIT:

I have made all necessary changes in my php.ini files,

```
post_max_size 128M
upload_max_filesize 100M
memory_limit 256M
```

Thanks,
Raju

Comment: please look this links maybe help you http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-bsd-nginx-413-request-entity-too-large/
https://rtcamp.com/tutorials/php/increase-file-upload-size-limit/

Comment: Hi Mohammad, I have looked for nginx but I couldnt find it on my server. I am sure, nginx isnt installed on my server, so I am confused of why I am receiving an error message which belongs to Nginx

Comment: first you mustbe sure ngix not installed on your server,but if you completely sure ,its maybe for security reason some server managers for confuse hackers use this trick

Comment: have you tried a `ps aux | grep nginx` to see if it is running?

Comment: Have you tried `which nginx`? That will give you the location of the executable, not the config file, but it should at least confirm whether or not nginx is installed.

Answer (score 310):

Source: [cybercity](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-bsd-nginx-413-request-entity-too-large/)

Edit the conf file of nginx:

```
nano /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Add a line in the `http`, `server` or `location` section:

```
client_max_body_size 100M;
```

Don't use `MB` it will not work, only the M!

Also do not forget to restart nginx:

```
systemctl restart nginx
```

Comment: When I do this my 413 turns into a 404.  I'm using Amazon Linux on EC2.  Also the nginx doc show a lowercase 'm'. http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_max_body_size

Comment: It's asking for a password to change the file. But I don't remember setting one. Am i missing something?

Comment: The path for nano should be nano /etc/nginx/nginx.conf .

Comment: Worked for me but NOTE: If your config already has a `http { }` section, add the rest inside of it! Adding a new `http {}` section will fail and give a `"http" directive is duplicate` error in the Nginx log.

Comment: I've edited the answer to make it clear that you can add the `client_max_body_size` directive either in the `http`, `server` or `location` section, not only in the `http` section. [See the docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_max_body_size).

Answer (score 54):

**-in  php.ini (inside /etc/php.ini)**

```
 max_input_time = 24000
 max_execution_time = 24000
 upload_max_filesize = 12000M
 post_max_size = 24000M
 memory_limit = 12000M
```

**-in nginx.conf(inside /opt/nginx/conf)**

```
client_max_body_size 24000M
```

Its working for my case

Comment: Hi Arun, the issue with our server is, I am unable to find nginx installed but its still gives nginx error

Comment: find nginx inside /opt or /etc. Inside nginx find conf folder then nginx.conf.

Comment: If above idea dont work, then search for nginx.conf inside whole Linux, by any search tool.

Comment: ` max_input_time = 24000`, 24000 is in milliseconds?

Comment: @RishabhAgrahari Seconds!
This sets the maximum time in seconds.
The default setting is -1, which means that max_execution_time is used instead. Set to 0 to allow unlimited time

Answer (score 34):

**First edit the Nginx configuration file (`nginx.conf`)**

Location: `sudo nano /etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

Add following codes:

```
http {
        client_max_body_size 100M;
}
```

**Then Add the following lines in PHP configuration file(`php.ini`)**

Location: `sudo gedit /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini`

Add following codes:

```
memory_limit = 128M 
post_max_size = 20M  
upload_max_filesize = 10M
```

Comment: I opened my `nginx.conf` file as instructed, but it was empty! I wasn't expecting that, but when I added your code it still worked...as I guess one would expect, but for some reason I wasn't and I was very happy when it did!

Answer (score 26):

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Then add a line in the http section

```
http {
    client_max_body_size 100M;
}
```

don't use MB only M.

```
systemctl restart nginx
```

then for php location

```
sudo gedit /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini
```

for nowdays maximum use php 7.0 or higher

```
sudo nano /etc/php/7.2/fpm/php.ini     //7.3,7.2 or 7.1 which php you use
```

check those increasing by your desire .

```
memory_limit = 128M 
post_max_size = 20M  
upload_max_filesize = 10M
```

restart php-fpm

```
service php-fpm restart
```

Answer (score 16):

I add the changes directly to my virtualhost instead the global config of nginx, like this:

```
   server {
     client_max_body_size 100M;
     ...
   }
```

And then I change the params in php.ini, like the comments above:

```
   max_input_time = 24000
   max_execution_time = 24000
   upload_max_filesize = 12000M
   post_max_size = 24000M
   memory_limit = 12000M
```

and what you can not forget is to restart nginx and php-fpm, in centos 7 is like this:

```
  systemctl restart nginx
  systemctl restart php-fpm
```

Answer (score 8):

Please enter domain nginx file :

```
nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/domain.set
```

Add to file this code

```
client_max_body_size 24000M;
```

If you get error use this command

```
nginx -t
```

Answer (score 8):

I got the same error and fixed it with the below steps.

1. At first, edit the nginx.conf file.

   `vi /etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

At the HTTP section, added the below line.

```
http {

    client_max_body_size 100M;
}
```

2. Finally restarted Nginx with the below command.

`systemctl restart nginx`

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that you made the necessary changes in your php.ini files:

You can resolve the issue by adding the following line in your nginx.conf file found in the following path:

```
/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

then edit the file using vim text editor as follows:

```
vi /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

and add client_max_body_size with a large enough value, for example:

```
client_max_body_size 20MB;
```

After that make sure you save using `:xi` or `:wq`

And then restart your nginx.

That's it.

Worked for me, hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

First of all you need to pay attention to the response status code:

If it says "413 Content Too Large" it is returned by php itself (php.ini file)

If it says "413 Request Entity Too Large", then it is returned by nginx (if you use one).

If it says "403 Forbidden" (if you have Modsecurity installed), then most likely it is returned by Modsecurity.

If it is returned by php, then you'll need to change:

"post_max_size"(applies for all the files sent inside the request)

"upload_max_filesize" (applies for an individual file separately)

In either

"/etc/php/8.2/fpm/php.ini"

Or

"/etc/php/8.2/cli/php.ini" (Nginx servers usually work with fpm).

If it is returned by nginx, then you need to add "client_max_body_size 22M;" directive to the .conf file of your website.

If it is returned by Modsecurity, then you need to change "SecRequestBodyLimit" directive in /etc/nginx/modsec/modsecurity.conf file to something like "SecRequestBodyLimit 23068672" (It is written in bytes)

Comment: Very helpful about which serivce is causing the problem. Helped a lot

Answer (score 2):

I got the upload working with above changes. But when I made the changes I started getting 404 response in file upload which lead me to do further debugging and figured out its a permission issue by checking nginx error.log

**Solution:**

Check the current user and group ownership on /var/lib/nginx.

```
$ ls -ld /var/lib/nginx
```

drwx------. 3 nginx nginx 17 Oct  5 19:31 /var/lib/nginx

This tells that a possibly non-existent user and group named nginx owns this folder. This is preventing file uploading.

In my case, the username mentioned in "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf"  was

```
user vagrant;
```

Change the folder ownership to the user defined in nginx.conf in this case vagrant.

```
$ sudo chown -Rf vagrant:vagrant /var/lib/nginx
```

Verify that it actually changed.

```
$ ls -ld /var/lib/nginx
drwx------. 3 vagrant vagrant 17 Oct  5 19:31 /var/lib/nginx
```

Reload nginx and php-fpm for safer sade.

```
$ sudo service nginx reload
$ sudo service php-fpm reload
```

The permission denied error should now go away. Check the error.log (based on nginx.conf error_log location).

```
$ sudo nano /path/to/nginx/error.log
```

Answer (score 2):

Anyone looking for a solution for Apache2 (Ubuntu 18 for me), you can edit:

```
/etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

And find/edit the line:

```
LimitRequestBody 7000000 #7mb
```

Answer (score 1):

Just open this file and ---

```
sudo vim  /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Add a line in the **http**, **server** or **location** section:

```
client_max_body_size 100M;
```

Then check nginx is okey or not by the following command

```
sudo nginx -t
```

If everything looks fine then you will get

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

Then restart nginx

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

I hope your purpose is served :)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was using nginx along with letsencrypt to put a ssl layer in front of my spring boot application.

Putting clint_max_body_size property in "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf" did not work for me.
Instead, I put this property inside the site specific conf file.

> sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/mywebsite.com

```
server {
    ...
    client_max_body_size 3M;
    ...
}
```

Post saving the above, restarted the nginx server and it worked !

> sudo service nginx stop

> sudo service nginx start

Answer (score 0):

Open file`/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`
Add or change `client_max_body_size 0;`

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
php -i
```

command or add:

```
phpinfo();
```

to get the location of configuration file.

Update these variables according to your need and server

```
max_input_time = 24000
max_execution_time = 24000
upload_max_filesize = 12000M
post_max_size = 24000M
memory_limit = 12000M
```

On Linux you will need to restart nginx / apache and phpfpm service so the new ini settings are loaded. On xampp, ammps you can restart these from control panel that comes with such applications.