# Not Able to import XML file in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I am trying to import XML file of my Blogspot blog to wordpress blog. But I have this error:

> 413 Request Entity Too Large

I have tried to increase the memory limit for `.htaccess` file as well as from `function.php` file.

```
post_max_size 128M
upload_max_filesize 100M
memory_limit 256M
```

I even tried to split XML file but don't find any free tool for it.

Comment: 413 Request Entity Too Large is Nginx error. Please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37916740/10894610).

Comment: If you using shared hosting adding code may not help.  you need to contact hosting support to increase these value from php.ini

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to edit the config file? You can add the following code:

```
define(‘WP_MEMORY_LIMIT’, ‘64M’);
define(‘WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT’, 128M’);
```

Edit the numbers as suited.
And do you have access to a file called php.ini? You can increase the values there too.