# 413 Request Entity Too Large nginx server in laravel homestead for windows

Tags: php, laravel

I am developing a site that needs a file upload. I am using Laravel homestead on windows OS. so when I try to upload i get the error 413 Request Entity Too Large. The server is Nginx/1.15.8 . How do I solve this?..most of the solution I have seen does not explain how to get the directory for the nginx configuration file for homestead using windows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [413 Request Entity Too Large - File Upload Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24306335/413-request-entity-too-large-file-upload-issue)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Then add a line in the http section

```
http {
    client_max_body_size 100M;
}
```

don't use MB only M.

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

then for php location

```
sudo gedit /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini
```

for nowdays maximum use php 7.0 or higher

```
sudo nano /etc/php/7.2/fpm/php.ini     //7.3,7.2 or 7.1 which php you use
```

check those increasing by your desire .

```
memory_limit = 128M 
post_max_size = 20M  
upload_max_filesize = 10M
```

restart php-fpm

```
sudo service php-fpm restart
```

Comment: it really solved my problem. I only had to make changes to the nginx server, because the php.ini  (7.3) default setting for my homestead version is ok.

Answer (score 7):

I solved the same problem like this:
Connect to vagrant trough ssh

```
vagrant ssh
```

Edit the conf file of nginx:

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Add a line to the HTTP section

```
http {
    ...
    client_max_body_size 100M;
}
```

Restart the Ngix server.

```
systemctl restart nginx
```

Locate the PHP configuration file (php.ini)

```
php --ini
```

Then edit the file (in my case)

```
sudo nano /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini
```

Set these two parameters:

```
post_max_size = 50M
upload_max_filesize = 50M
```

After modifying php.ini file, you need to restart Vagrant:

```
vagrant reload
```

Comment: this worked for me!  (specifically just the Nginx part) thank you!

Comment: Why is this not the default?