# 413 Nginx - Entity too large only with certain files

Tags: php, nginx, server

I'm using `Nginx` which have this configuration:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  4;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    client_max_body_size 100M;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    # Switch logging to console out to view via Docker
    #access_log /dev/stdout;
    #error_log /dev/stderr;

    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-available/*.conf;
}
```

and also, `php-fpm` actually contains the following `php.ini` settings:

```
upload_max_filesize = 100M
max_file_uploads = 20
max_input_time = 60
memory_limit = 32M
```

When I upload images with a size of 7Mb no issue appear, but when I upload a file with 1200Kb with `.mp3` extension, I get:

> 413 - Entity Too Large

this happen only with audio files, someone could explain me why?

Seems like `Nginx` cannot read the file weight from certain extension files.

Comment: Check the nginX error log and FPM error log. If there is not enough information - you may need to run nginX in `debug` mode.

Comment: @IVOGELOV Checked both, and nothing is displayed when I upload the file

Comment: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/debugging/

Comment: dup.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24306335/413-request-entity-too-large-file-upload-issue

Comment: What method are you using to upload the file? Assuming a web form, what does a minimal version of the form html look like?