# "Path cannot be empty" laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to save a pdf file in the storage folder but when I insert a file in my form and I click on the button, it displays me the error "Path cannot be empty". However, the path is not empty.
Here is my function that allows me to do this :

```
public function getFilenametostore(Request $request): string
{
    $filenamewithextension = $request->file('profile_pdf')->getClientOriginalName();

    $filename = pathinfo($filenamewithextension, PATHINFO_FILENAME);

    //get file extension
    $extension = $request->file('profile_pdf')->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $time = time();
    //filename to store
    $filenametostore = $filename . '_' . $time . '.' . $extension;

    //The problem is here
    $request->file('profile_pdf')->storeAs('profile_pdfs', $filenametostore);
    

    return $filenametostore;
}
```

in storage, there is: storage/app/public/profile_pdfs/

My Form :

```
<form action="{{url('poste')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
@csrf

    <div class="mt-2">
        <label class=" block text-sm text-gray-600" for="cus_email">Upload</label>
        <input class="px-2 py-2 text-gray-700 rounded" type="file" name="profile_pdf" id="exampleInputFile">
    </div>


    <div class="mt-4">
      <button class="px-4 py-1 text-white font-light tracking-wider bg-gray-900 rounded" type="submit">Publier</button>
    </div>


</form>
```

My controller :

```
if($files = $request->hasFile('profile_pdf'))
    {

        $filenametostore = $this->getFilenametostore($request);


        $p = new Poste;
        $p->pdf = $filenametostore;
        $p->save();

        return redirect()->route('poste.index');
    }
```

Comment: please can you paste a code snippet of your HTML form

Comment: Is it this function that throws the error? or when you save your model? I guess you've added the 'path' as required in your validation? Add the controller code that calls this function and saves the model.

Comment: I have changed my comment.

Comment: I found the problem, it is because of the putFileAs() function in the vendor with $file->getRealPath()

Answer (score 9):

I just solved this problem. If your website is hosted on windows server go to your temp folder (C:\Windows\Temp) and right click -> properties -> edit your user's permissions to full control like this.

[image: go to properties]

[image: edit permissions]

[image: select your user and check 'full control']

[image: finally apply]

after that if you get an alert just click ok.
Don't forget to login with your administrator user to able to edit permissions.

Comment: Only helpful for Windows users.

Answer (score 6):

Go to `php.ini` file uncomment `upload_tmp_dir` and set the value `c:\windows\temp`

`;upload_tmp_dir =`

Replace like this
`upload_tmp_dir = c:\windows\temp`
if you use windows

Comment: In case you are using Laragon, Uncomment upload_tmp_dir and set value to "C:/laragon/tmp" inside php.ini

Comment: This answer solved my problem for Laravel  version 10

Comment: What if you're not using Windows? Guess this isn't helpful in that case.

Answer (score 2):

You can try one of these method

```
$fileName = $file.'.'.$ext;
$request->file->storeAs($path, $fileName);
// or 
Storage::disk('local')->put($path . '/' . $fileName , $request->file);
```

Answer (score 1):

When uploading large files, for some reason the Path gets set to empty in the Laravel Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile class, unless your php.ini `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` are set appropriately.

Find the loaded php.ini (in my case the correct path is `/etc/php/8.2/fpm/php.ini`) — you can only find the REAL loaded file by checking phpinfo() — the `php --ini` command sometimes does not show the proper path.

In my case I had to allow users to upload huge SQL dump files, so I set the values like this:

`upload_max_filesize = 100M`

`post_max_size = 100M`

NOTE: If you are running nginx on your web server, you have to add  `client_max_body_size 100M;` into your nginx config, in the server block, otherwise your users will get ugly **413 Request Entity Too Large** errors when uploading (SEE: [413 Request Entity Too Large - File Upload Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24306335/413-request-entity-too-large-file-upload-issue))