# showing php 413 error while uploading a 2gb file in php

Tags: php

[image: error screenshot]
first of all i have these settings in my htaccess

```
php_value memory_limit 4000M
php_value post_max_size 3000M
php_value upload_max_filesize 2500M
php_value max_execution_time 300
```

And also checked the phpinfo page , which shows the same data as of my htaccess file.

But still "Request Entity Too Large" 413 Error shows while uploading a 2gb zip file through an upload script.Why?

Comment: but it's a local server running in my own system.localhost:8080

Comment: I think you need configure apache, not just php. https://serverfault.com/questions/256838/apache-responding-with-request-entity-too-large

Comment: This is the code i found there SecRequestBodyLimit 10485760

Comment: what is it and where to use it??? I don't have any idea

Comment: Put it in the .htaccess file and restart the server.

Comment: not working brother... same problem..

Comment: i have added a screenshot of that page

Comment: Your question is much like [this one](https://serverfault.com/questions/959964/413-error-in-apache-even-though-my-post-is-much-smaller-than-the-max-limit). From the screenshot, it's not a apache or php error, it's returned from your post request, so you may check your script.

Comment: But how small size files are uploading so smoothly with this script??

Comment: There are limits in the web server for how large a file it will handle. It is fast with small files because it is local (the data doesn't have far to go), but even fast data can hit a configured limit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [413 Request Entity Too Large - File Upload Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24306335/413-request-entity-too-large-file-upload-issue)