# Can't upload file greater than 1 mb in php and nginx which is running in docker

Tags: php, docker, nginx

I can't upload files more than 1mb to the php site. Getting error

```
[warn] 30#30: *49 a client request body is buffered to a temporary file /var/cache/nginx/client_temp/0000000003, client: 172.18.0.1, server: localhost, request: "POST /includes/..... HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost", referrer:
```

Tried editing nginx file and uploads.ini

uploads.ini given as

```
RUN touch /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini \
    && echo "file_uploads = On" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini \
    && echo "memory_limit = 64M" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini \
    && echo "upload_max_filesize = 64M" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini \
    && echo "post_max_size = 64M" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini \
    && echo "max_execution_time = 600" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini
```

default.conf given as

```
client_max_body_size 20M;
client_body_buffer_size 10M;
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    server_name localhost;
```

After modifying the files getting nginx 500 error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [413 Request Entity Too Large - File Upload Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24306335/413-request-entity-too-large-file-upload-issue)